# One hard bounce should mark subscriber to Held status instead of waiting for 3 bounces to happen. Is it possible in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, subscriber-key

Can We mark one Hard bounce to Held status to avoid further bounces to happen and if they update their email address then I should able to mark them Active again. How to achieve this in SFMC

Comment: Yes, you need to open a support ticket and ask them to change that rule in your account

Comment: And you can always bring then back to active by changing their status on All Subscribers list

Comment: Also to note, if it is a hard bounce from a 'trusted domain' (gmail, etc.) it will go to held after 1 hard bounce.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.